# parity invariance of Einstein, Maxwell and Dirac Lagrangians

Tags: general-relativity, maxwell-equations, dirac-equation, parity

How can we show that Einstein, Maxwell and Dirac Lagrangians are parity invariant?

Answer (score 4):

Parity is a symmetry that we impose to the Dirac and Maxwell Lagrangian because we know experimentally that electromagnetism conserves parity. Demanding parity invariance will then tell you how Dirac spinors and vectors transform under such a symmetry. The correct transformation properties are:

$\bullet$ Spinors: $$\mathcal{P}\thinspace\psi(t,x)\mathcal{P}^\dagger\ =\ \gamma^0\ \psi\thinspace(t,-x)\ ,$$
$$\mathcal{P}\thinspace\bar{\psi}\thinspace(t,x)\mathcal{P}^\dagger\ =\   \psi^\dagger\thinspace(t,-x)\ ,$$

$\bullet$ Vectors:

$$\mathcal{P}\thinspace V^\mu\thinspace(t,x)\mathcal{P}^\dagger\ =\  \eta_{\mu\nu}\thinspace V^\nu\thinspace(t,-x)\ =\ V_\mu(t,-x)$$

Here by vectors I mean quantities such as the potential $A^\mu$, the partial derivative $\partial^\mu$ or the current $\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\psi$.

You can check that these are the transformation properties you want. The Dirac Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L}_D=\bar{\psi}(i\gamma_\mu\partial^\mu-m)\psi.$$

It is Parity invariant since both the mass and kinetic term are Parity invariant:

$$\mathcal{P}\bar{\psi}\psi\mathcal{P}^\dagger\ =\ \mathcal{P}\bar{\psi}\mathcal{P}^\dagger\thinspace\mathcal{P}\psi\mathcal{P}^\dagger\ =\ \psi^\dagger\gamma^0\psi\ =\ \bar{\psi}\psi.$$

$$\mathcal{P}\thinspace\bar{\psi}\gamma_\mu\partial^\mu\psi\mathcal{P}^\dagger\ =\ \mathcal{P}\bar{\psi}\mathcal{P}^\dagger\thinspace\gamma_\mu\mathcal{P}\partial^\mu\mathcal{P}^\dagger\mathcal{P}\psi\mathcal{P}^\dagger\ =\ \psi^\dagger\gamma_\mu\gamma^0\partial_\mu\psi\ =\ \bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu\psi$$

where in the last equality we used the property $\gamma^0\gamma^\mu=\gamma_\mu\gamma^0$.

The Maxwell Lagrangian is

$$\mathcal{L}_M\ = \ -\frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$$

where the Maxwell tensor is defined as $F^{\mu\nu}=\partial^\mu A^\nu-\partial^\nu A^\mu$. From this definition it is clear that each index in $F^{\mu\nu}$ transforms as a vector, so

$$\mathcal{P} F^{\mu\nu}\mathcal{P}^\dagger=F_{\mu\nu}.$$

Consequently Maxwell's lagrangian is parity invaiant.

By Einstein Lagrangian, you mean the Einstein-Hilbert action? or Einsteins equations?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes I mean that Einstein-Hilbert action.

But here I did not undestand why the index μ at downstairs in this transformation. PVμ(t,x)P† = ημνVν(t,−x) = Vμ(t,−x)
Also the transformed vector depend on −x, is it different from Vμ(t,x)? why the difference is not different sign in front of the vector as in Euclidian space. Also is it important the choosing of the signiture of the metric -+++ or +---? thanks a lot

Comment: Why the matrices $\gamma_{\mu}$ do not transform as a vector!,